# how to copy from text box to struct C#

Tags: c#, .net, struct

I need to copy the strings from text box to struct. is there any way to do it? here's what am trying:

```
public unsafe struct mystruc
{
    public byte[] install_name; // size limit 32 bytes
    public byte[] install_id;   // size limit 4 bytes
    public byte[] model_name;   // size limit 4 bytes
};

private void read_b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mystruc mstruc1 = new mystruc();

    //copy from textbox to struct    
    mstruc.install_name = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(installation_name_tb.Text);
    mstruc.install_id = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(installation_id_tb.Text);
    mstruc.model_name = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(model_tb.Text);    
}
```

and also other way round. its not working.. :( any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you using the `unsafe` keyword? Also, what do you want that you haven't done already?

Comment: am using Marshal in my prog..

Comment: What output are you getting from the textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you going to use this struct - I believe to invoke some Win32 style API. So the correct implementation would depend upon what that API is looking for. For example, if it is expecting ASCII characters (char), you need to use [ASCIIEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx). If is expecting unicode characters (WCHAR) then u should use [UnicodeEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.aspx). I would advise you share that api to get more useful answers.

**EDIT**: I am not certain if you are invoking any unmanaged DLL or how have you decided your structure layout but following info may be useful:

If the idea is to write contents of structure where you are assuming it to have length of 40 bytes (three inline arrays of 32, 4 and 4 bytes) then it won't work "as is" in .NET. This is because, array are reference types (pointers to memory somewhere else) and .NET may choose field offset in order have aligned word boundaries - so solution is to use attributes to mark that structure layout. For example,

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ascii)]
public struct mystruc
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    [FieldOffset(0x00)]
    public byte[] install_name; // size limit 32 bytes

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    [FieldOffset(0x33)]
    public byte[] install_id;   // size limit 4 bytes

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    [FieldOffset(0x37)]
    public byte[] model_name;   // size limit 4 bytes
}
```

Here, we are saying that we will layout structure explicitly (using field offset) and then provided information for each field. This struct would be probably equivalent of what you wants. Or you have to play with these attributes as per your requirments.

Comment: no...i need to write some settings into NV-RAM(non volatile) of camera..details entered in UI text box are stored in struct then converting it to byte[],pass to writeEEPROM()...

Comment: @ajith, wherever you are writing this data, it is expected to be in some format - right? (as opposed to only your program that is going to read/write data). So that format must be specifying that what install_name means and what is expected in those raw bytes?

Comment: @vinay:i dint get you...whatever you enter in text box,convert it to byte array and write,then read it back and display

Comment: @ajith, you must be using some unmanaged API (dll call) to write to EPROM - right? How had you decided that mystruc has 3 bytes arrays of some fixed length? Please also see my edit in answer.

Comment: public int WriteEEPROM(int Adr, byte[] pcString, int count)
        {
            return uEyeCamera.WriteEEPROM(Adr,pcString,count);
        }

Comment: @ajith, and what is the signature of uEyeCamera.WriteEEPROM?